# Wordpress "500 Internal Server Error" when posting comments

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is acting crazy when posting comments, showing a "500 Internal Server Error" every time a comment is submitted trough the comment form.

The comment is inserted successfully but you get the error screen, this does not happen when submitting an empty form, then you get the error page from wordpress stating that you have to write something before commenting.

Is there anybody with a solution for this besides a reinstall?

Thanks

Comment: What are you hosting this on? Where does your PHP install log errors? If you're on Linux try looking in /var/log/httpd/error_log or on IIS on Windows try the event log.

Comment: Hi Rup thanks for the answer. I'm on Linux but I don't find the error_log file. There is no such directory as /var/log/httpd/

Comment: have you modified any of the theme files recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Anca, but this was not the case of malfunctioning plugins or themes.

The problem was related to the email service of the server. Since we are not using the email service in this domain we were experiencing problems with form submitting. Turning off the email service fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the default theme and deactivating all your plugins - especially any that you recently installed that have to do with commenting.

If you are on shared hosting on Linux, you might be able to get to your error log through the domain control panel.